# ADODB Recordset issue with LONG Variable from Oracle

Tags: json, excel, vba, oracle, adodb

I have following code from which I am accessing two columns. 1st column is of `varchar` type but 2nd column is `Long` type.

I am not able to get the complete string from recordset variable. Data in `Long` type variable is JSON string. Code is as follows.

```vb
For i = 2 To lastrow
    sQuery = "select TCSCOMPANY_ID, TCS3TVGRID from (select TCSCOMPANY_ID,TCDMODIFIED_DATE, TCS3TVGRID from MAR_TRN_3TV_CHART where TCSCOMPANY_ID='" & Sheets("LIST").Cells(i, 1) & "' order by TCDMODIFIED_DATE desc) where ROWNUM=1"
    'MsgBox sQuery
    cmd.ActiveConnection = con
    cmd.CommandText = sQuery
    Set rs = cmd.Execute()

    If i = 2 Then
        Workbooks("" & wkbkname).Worksheets("TEMP").Cells(1, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs
    Else
        lastrowtemp = Workbooks("" & wkbkname).Worksheets("TEMP").Cells(rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Workbooks("" & wkbkname).Worksheets("TEMP").Cells(lastrowtemp + 1, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs
    End If
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
Next

con.Close
```

`For` loop is used to get records with multiple ID's. When I execute same query on Oracle toll it works fine and gives result as follows.

[image: JSON Data]

What I should get is that big string but what I am getting is the other. Please help in same.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7980483/extract-oracle-long-to-string-in-vba

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Tim Williams. But the problem is with the recordset variable. I tried to print it using **Debug.Print** it shows the small string only.

Comment: Did you try using `GetChunk()` as shown in the linked post?